# Array Implode in php

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array of the following format:

```
$var = Array
     ( 
     [0] => Array
         (
        [name] => Harry
          )

      [1] => Array
         (
        [name] => Wayne
          )

      )
 Array
     (
     [0] => Array
         (
        [name] => Wayne
         )
```

I want to implode this array such that i get it in the format:

```
 Harry,Wayne
 Wayne
```

From What I have Tried I am getting it in format:

```
Harry,Wayne
Harry,Wayne,Wayne
```

**What I have Tried** (Not important as its wrong)

```
foreach($var as $a){
 foreach($a as $b){
 }$c[] = $b
   }
 $imp = implode(',',$c);
```

$var is fetched from database using fetch_array.

```
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->where('id', $Id);
    $this->db->from('info');
    $row = $this->db->get();
    $var = $row->result_array();
```

where $Id is array containing certain user ids.

Comment: Seems like both are different arrays.

Comment: What about the second array block? it is a different array right? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach($var as $a){
  $m = '';
  $delim = '';
  foreach($a as $k){
     $m .= $delim . $k['name'];
     $delim = ',';
  }

  $c[] = $m;
}

foreach($c as $d){
  echo $d;
}
```

Comment: @Venu, it is always better to have your own algo rather than using built in functions. That will not only increase your skills but also it increase your finding solutions skills

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($var as $a)
{
    unset($temp);
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        $temp[] = $b['name'];
    }
    $c[] = implode(",", $temp);
}

// output all the names
foreach ($c as $csvNames)
{
    echo $csvNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore those hard-coded loops. There is a recursive function for it.

```
array_walk_recursive($var, create_function('$val, $key', 'array_push($obj, $val);'), &$output);
echo implode(",",$output);
```